# Jethro Tull - Thick as a Brick with black band logo instead of a red one

Tags: artwork, jethro-tull

I was just listening to Jehtro Tull's Thick as a Brick on Spotify and I noticed that the album cover had a red square in the upper red corner in which you can see the band name. See the image for a more visual approach to what I mean:

[image: Thick as a Brick]

Now I'm quite sure that my LP version is exactly the same but with a black corner instead of a red one. I'm not at home right now so I can't take a picture, but I can't seem to find any evidence that this edition exists.

Now the question is: is this an official release?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=thick+as+a+brick+cover&safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJhsyIytjRAhVRF8AKHXNQApwQ7AkIOA&biw=1124&bih=1327 shows a dozen variants, some with & without the red corner.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm talking about the LP version. A CD & DVD version is the one without a corner

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think it can be an official relase.
On [Discogs](https://www.discogs.com/Jethro-Tull-Thick-As-A-Brick/master/38308), I found some releases with a black corner:

- [Venezuela](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Jethro-Tull-Thick-As-A-Brick-Tan-Embotado-Como-Un-Ladrillo/release/8021638)
- [Grece](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Jethro-Tull-Thick-As-A-Brick/release/6310940)
- [France](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Jethro-Tull-Thick-As-A-Brick/release/4695914)
- . . . and maybe others.

[image: Jethro Tull]

Even black corner with red letters in [Italy](https://www.discogs.com/fr/Jethro-Tull-Thick-As-A-Brick/release/7110697).

You can check your record number once you find it, and see it on the list.